# Query which will delete other table reference as well as from main table

Tags: rdbms

I have a requirement of deleting records from the Postgres database tables.

We have a Customer table which is the main table, this table contains a primary key which is used in so many other tables as a FOREIGN KEY, I want to delete one of the customers as well as its reference used in other tables. Is there any way to delete the customer from main table as well as from other tables which contains foreign key.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Are you using MySQL, MS SQL Server or Postgresql?

Comment: Don't just randomly add RDBMS tags, tag the RDBMS you are *really* using and **only** that RDBMS. I have removed all the conflicting tags; please [edit] your question and only readd the tag for RDBMS you are actually using.

Comment: Also, depending on your implementation and RDBMS this may automatically happen if you have `CASCADE` (or the RDBMS equivalent) enabled.

Comment: I am using postgresql.

Answer (score 0):

In the other tables, you want a [cascading delete foreign key reference](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/ddl-constraints.html#DDL-CONSTRAINTS-FK).  You can create one in the database using:

```
alter table othertable add constraint fk_othertable_customerid
    foreign key (customerid) references customers(customerid)
        on delete cascade;
```

Note:  This assumes that `customerid` is the name of the column in both tables and that it is already defined in the other tables.

A cascading foreign key constraint does exactly what you specify.  When a row is deleted in the reference table, then all related rows are deleted.

If you already have foreign key constraints on `customerid`, then drop the existing constraint and add the cascading version.

Answer (score 0):

This assumes that customerid is the name of the column in both tables and that it is already defined in the other tables.

A cascading foreign key constraint does exactly what you specify. When a row is deleted in the reference table, then all related rows are deleted.

If you already have foreign key constraints on customerid, then drop the existing constraint and add the cascading version.

Share
Improve this answer
Follow